# Why does Django Rest Framework try to authenticate the request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm encountering an error that can be "resolved" by simply adding to `INSTALLED_APPS` (without `migrate`):

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
```

Based on the debug output, it seems this error is occurring because Django Rest Framework is trying to authenticate the request, which requires the Auth app, which requires Permissions and ContentTypes, all of which have been removed. The APIView uses only `query_params` from `request`, nothing else. It accepts the global DRF settings as shown:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': ('common.rest.JSONRenderer',),
    'DEFAULT_CONTENT_NEGOTIATION_CLASS': 'common.rest.IgnoreNegotiation',
}
```

Debug output:

```
RuntimeError at /mac/pins/
Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://django/mac/pins/
Django Version: 1.10.5
Python Executable: /home/admin/env/bin/python3.6
Python Version: 3.6.0
Python Path: ['/home/admin/src', '/home/admin/env/bin', '/home/admin/env/lib/python36.zip', '/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6', '/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6', '/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Server time: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 00:54:33 +0000
Installed Applications:
['myapp']
Installed Middleware:
()

Traceback:  

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  58.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  483.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in handle_exception
  443.             self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
  471.             self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in initial
  393.         self.perform_authentication(request)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in perform_authentication
  319.         request.user

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in __getattribute__
  379.             return super(Request, self).__getattribute__(attr)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in user
  196.             self._authenticate()

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in _authenticate
  352.         self._not_authenticated()

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py" in _not_authenticated
  363.         if api_settings.UNAUTHENTICATED_USER:

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in __getattr__
  220.             val = perform_import(val, attr)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in perform_import
  163.         return import_from_string(val, setting_name)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/settings.py" in import_from_string
  177.         module = import_module(module_path)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  126.     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py" in <module>
  6. from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py" in <module>
  138. class ContentType(models.Model):

File "/home/admin/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in __new__
  113.                         "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)

Exception Type: RuntimeError at /mac/pins/
Exception Value: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

**Why** is it trying to authenticate the request? How can I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trying to authenticate the request.  You don't have any authenticators so it skipped over an empty tuple and went to:

```
352.         self._not_authenticated()
```

However the unauthenticated user object in rest framework defaults to this:

```
# Authentication
'UNAUTHENTICATED_USER': 'django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser',
```

So maybe you'll need to provide your own unauthenticated user model, if you don't want to pull in `django.contrib.auth`.